# htaccess url rewrite to drop the end of a url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a huge number of urls similar to

```
http://example.com/index.php?cPath=371_1659_1660&main_page=products_categories
```

I need to be able to rewrite them so that they are simply

```
http://example.com/index.php?cPath=371_1659_1660
```

I've tried several times but I just end up with Error 500 and my site is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(^|&)main_page=products_categories(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [R=301,L]